# Scala filter on a list by index

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I wanted to write it functionally, and the best I could do was:

```
list.zipWithIndex.filter((tt:Tuple2[Thing,Int])=>(tt._2%3==0)).unzip._1
```

to get elements 0, 3, 6,...

Is there a more readable Scala idiom for this?

Comment: How do you define functional?  Are for comprehensions acceptable?  Streams?  Iterators?  Or do you mean *only* the List combinator functions?

Comment: I just trying to exclude procedural answers.  My chief concerns here is readability and succinctness.

Comment: Then I guess om-nom-nom's indices method and the first, naive for-comprehension in my answer both qualify.

Comment: I agree.  Need a chance to play with them in code before I officially accept.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If efficiency is not an issue, you could do the following:

```
list.grouped(3).map(_.head)
```

Note that this constructs intermediate lists.

Alternatively you can use a for-comprehension:

```
for {
  (x,i) <- list zipWithIndex
  if i % 3 == 0
} yield x
```

This is of course almost identical to your original solution, just written differently.

My last alternative for you is the use of collect on the zipped list:

```
list.zipWithIndex.collect {
  case (x,i) if i % 3 == 0 => x
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Not much clear, but still:

```
xs.indices.collect { case i if i % 3 == 0 => xs(i) }
```

Comment: You might want to add that indexed access should be `O(1)`, otherwise this will not perform `O(n)`.

Answer (score 5):

A nice, functional solution, without creating temporary vectors, lists, and so on:

```
def everyNth[T](xs: List[T], n:Int): List[T] = xs match {
  case hd::tl => hd::everyNth(tl.drop(n-1), n)
  case Nil => Nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clojure has a [`take-nth`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/take-nth) function that does what you want, but I was surprised to find that there's not an equivalent method in Scala. You could code up a similar recursive solution based off the Clojure code, or you could read this blog post:

[Scala collections: Filtering each n-th element](http://www.krzysztofbialek.com/2011/02/scala-collections-filtering-each-n-th.html)

The author actually has a nice graph at the end showing the relative performance of each of his solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like in Octave mathematical program.

```
val indices = 0 until n by 3  // Range 0,3,6,9 ...
```

and then I needed some way to select the indices from a collection. Obviously I had to have a collection with random-access O(1). Like `Array` or `Vector`. For example here I use `Vector`. To wrap the access into a nice DSL I'd add an implicit class:

```
implicit class VectorEnrichedWithIndices[T](v:Vector[T]) {
  def apply(indices:TraversableOnce[Int]):Vector[T] = {
    // some implementation 
    indices.toVector.map(v)
  }
}
```

The usage would look like:

```
val vector = list.toVector
val every3rdElement = vector(0 until vector.size by 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, how about this?

```
val l = List(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
for (i <- (0 to l.size - 1 by 3).toList) yield l(i)
//res0: List[Int] = List(10, 7, 4, 1)
```

which can be made more general by

```
def seqByN[A](xs: Seq[A], n: Int): Seq[A] = for (i <- 0 to xs.size - 1 by n) yield xs(i)

scala> seqByN(List(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0), 3)
res1: Seq[Int] = Vector(10,7,4,1)

scala> seqByN(List(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0), 3).toList
res2: Seq[Int] = List(10,7,4,1)

scala> seqByN(List[Int](), 3)
res1: Seq[Int] = Vector()
```

But by *functional* do you mean only using the various List combinator functions?  Otherwise, are Streams functional enough?

```
def fromByN[A](xs: List[A], n: Int): Stream[A] = if (xs.isEmpty) Stream.empty else
  xs.head #:: fromByN(xs drop n, n)

scala> fromByN(List(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0), 3).toList
res17: List[Int] = List(10, 7, 4, 1)
```