# Scala: function with inner recursive function

Tags: scala, recursion

I am writing a function which removes kth element from the list (this comes from scala 99 problems) and was puzzled by a specific behaviour
this recursive function works fine

```
def removeAt3(startPos:Int,  inputList :List[Symbol]) =  {
  // will use inner recursive function 
    def removeAtRecursive(position:Int, lst:List[Symbol]):List[Symbol] = (position, lst) match {
    case (_, Nil) => println("end of list");List[Symbol]()
    case (any, h::tl) => if (any == startPos) removeAtRecursive(any + 1, tl) else  h::removeAtRecursive(any+1, tl)
  }
  removeAtRecursive(0, inputList)
}
```

But this version does not.

```
def removeAt4(startPos:Int,  inputList :List[Symbol]) =  {
  // will use inner recursive function 
  def removeAtRecursive(position:Int, lst:List[Symbol]):List[Symbol] = (position, lst) match {
    case (_, Nil) => println("end of list");List[Symbol]()
    case (startPos, h::tl) => removeAtRecursive(position + 1, tl)
    case (any, h::tl) => h::removeAtRecursive(any+1, tl)

  }
  removeAtRecursive(0, inputList)
}
removeAt4(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f))
```

In fact Eclipse keeps on complaining that the `case(any, h::tl)` is unreachable.

But if I call `removeAt4(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f))` shouldn't `case(startPos, h::tl)` be effectively translated in `case(3, h::tl)`?

Answer (score 0):

In your second example `case (startPos, h::tl)` does not do what you think it does. It defines a tuple where a new variable, startPos is bound to the first element of the tuple. In essence, it is identical to your final case `case (any, h::tl)` so the last case is unreachable.

Incidentally, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814522/scala-filter-on-a-list-by-index) has an answer that you can adapt:

```
def removeAt(startPos:Int, inputList:List[Symbol]) = {
    list.zipWithIndex.collect {
        case (x,i) if i != startPos == 0 => x
    }
}
```